# C# - No implicit reference conversion from 'T' to 'System.IComparable<T>'

Tags: c#, generics

I have taken the following class from another SO question:

```
    public class Range<T> where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        public T Minimum { get; set; }
        public T Maximum { get; set; }

        public override string ToString() { return String.Format("[{0} - {1}]", Minimum, Maximum); }

        public Boolean IsValid() { return Minimum.CompareTo(Maximum) <= 0; }

        public Boolean ContainsValue(T value)
        {
            return (Minimum.CompareTo(value) <= 0) && (value.CompareTo(Maximum) <= 0);
        }
    }
```

I would like, however, to create another class that contains many instances of this class, and can execute a foreach loop on them all, returning true if the number passed is contained in any one of the ranges:

```
    public class Ranges<T> where T : Range<T>
    {
        private List<Range<T>> rangelist;

        public void add(Range<T> range)
        {
            rangelist.Add(range);
        }

        public Boolean ContainsValue(T value)
        {
            foreach (Range<T> range in rangelist)
            {
                if (range.ContainsValue(value)) return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```

However, i am getting the error `The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Range<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'T' to 'System.IComparable<T>'.`

What exactly is going wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you rewrite your second class slightly, you'll see why:

```
public class Ranges<U> where U : Range<U>
{
    private List<Range<U>> rangelist;

    public void add(Range<U> range)
    {
        rangelist.Add(range);
    }
    ...
}
```

The error is telling you the compiler does not know if `U` is convertible to `IComparable<U>`, which is apparent from the declaration of `Ranges<U>` and `Range<T>` (`Range<T>` does not implement any interfaces).

More importantly, you have a recursing generic argument!

If `U` is `Range<U>`, then your class looks like `Ranges<Range<T>>` where `T` is `U`, and so on and so forth.

From what I can tell, you're not looking to write:

```
Ranges<Range<int>> x = ...;
```

But rather:

```
Ranges<int> x = ...;
```

Which would mean:

```
public class Ranges<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private List<Range<T>> rangelist;

    ...
```

Answer (score 9):

You don't seem to need the constraint `where T : Range<T>`

Just repeat the comparable constraint:

```
public class Ranges<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
}
```

Comment: Wow, you just saved my freakin week!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need new classes for that, use linq.

```
list1.All(x=>list2.Any(y=>y == x))
```

UPDATE:  You are saying : I would like, however, to create another class that contains many instances of this class, and can execute a foreach loop on them all, returning true if the number passed is contained in any one of the ranges:

So effectively you have list of lists. Or more generally `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerables`.

There is enough standard generic data structures to handle this scenario

```
   public static class ListOfListExtention {

        public static bool ContainAny( this List<List<int>> lists, int number ) {
             return lists.Any(l=>l.Any(x=>x == number))
        }

   }
```

Which can be rewritten in more generic way using IComparable interface

```
   public static class ListOfListExtention {

        public static bool ContainAny<T>
           (this List<List<int>> lists, int value ) where T : IComparable<T> {
             return lists.Any(l=>l.Any(x=>x == value))
        }

   }
```

So to compare with accepted answer, why wrap List in new class if you can just have one extension method.

Comment: If you went into more detail, and put this into context with my question this might be a good alternative answer.

Comment: You do not need `IComparable<T>` to use `==`. This does not really do the same thing as the OP's original.

Comment: @user7116 it hasn't to be the same, it is what he says he wants to do.